# Ajax url navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make something similar to GitHub that loads content based on the url.

I saw this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586661/url-navigation-in-an-ajax-based-website), but I do not want to use a plugin. I would like to write my code manually.

One article I saw [here](http://yensdesign.com/2008/11/creating-ajax-websites-based-on-anchor-navigation/), they kept checking the document.location.hash for any changes, then load the content. Is there a better way to achieve this?

The following are what Im thinking about:

1. Load content on page load.
2. Load content on url change.
3. Change url from anchor tag without reloading page.
4. SEO.
5. Back button.

Comment: I'm guessing you want the functionality of when you use the back button it correctly steps back through ajax page navigation you've used?

Comment: have you looked at jQuery.History? It does use the monitoring of the hash change via x-browser method and in my experience it works well.

Answer (score 3):

Some browsers support a [`hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) event and a `window.onhashchange` event handler:

> The hashchange event fires when a window's hash changes (see location.hash).

but some don't, the timer hack is used for browsers that don't have a `hashchange` event.

Your best bet is to grab an existing plugin or library and figure out how it works, that should help you get past the various browser hacks and special cases:

- [Sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/)
- [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want some resemblance of SEO you still need real links, and then replace the click events with some javascript that utilisies https://github.com/browserstate/History.js this. Then you just setup the events so it loades via AJAX on History triggers.

The History.js script i linked uses the new History api introduced in newer browsers, but will fallback if not supported.

On page reloads/first page loads, you might want to have the first content served from the server - so Google has some actual content to cache.

Comment: How would I handle real links? For ex. I get a control as follows: `/MyController/GetProfileInfo`. But If I go to that url, It would not render a master page or any styles, etc.

Comment: @Lol coder  You should set up your code so when it comes via AJAX you don't render your master page, but when it isn't by AJAX it does render it. Methods include checking headers, but you could always do a cheap and dirty trick by sending an extra value via POST so the server allways knows its ajax

Answer (score 0):

I've found this on a "codeigniter" similar question, but should answer your question.

[CodeIgniter + jQuery(ajax) + HTML5 pushstate: How can I make a clean navigation with real URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638738/codeigniter-jqueryajax-html5-pushstate-how-can-i-make-a-clean-navigation#answer-6639119)

This is a pretty light solution:
https://github.com/cairo140/html5-history-example

Check the demo here:
http://cairo140.github.io/html5-history-example/one.html

Hope it can help