# CodeIgniter + jQuery(ajax) + HTML5 pushstate: How can I make a clean navigation with real URLs?

Tags: html, url, codeigniter, jquery, pushstate

I'm currently trying to build a new website, nothing special, nice and small, but I'm stuck at the very beginning.
My problems are clean URLs and page navigation. I want to do it "the right way".

**What I would like to have:**

- I use CodeIgniter to get clean URLs like
  *"www.example.com/hello/world"*
- jQuery helps me using ajax, so I can
  .load() additional content
- Now I want to use HTML5 features like pushstate to
  get rid of the # in the URL

It should be possible to go back and forth without a page refresh but the page will still display the right content according to the current URL.

It should also be possible to reload a page without getting a 404 error. The site should exist thanks to CodeIgniter. *(there is a controller and a view)*

**For example:**
A very basic website. Two links, called "foo" and "bar" and a emtpy div box beneath them.
The basic URL is example.com
When you click on "foo" the URL changes to *"example.com/foo"* without reloading and the div box gets new content with jQuery .load(). The same goes for the other link, just of course different content and URL.
After clicking "foo" and then "bar" the back button will bring me back to *"example.com/foo"* with the according content. If I load this link directly or refresh the page, it will look the same. No 404 error or something.

Just think about this page and tell me how you would do this.
I would really love to have this kind of navigation and so I tried several things.

---

**So far...**
I know how to use CodeIgniter to get the URLs like this. I know how to use jQuery to load additional content and while I don't fully understand the html5 pushstate stuff, I at least got it to work somehow.
But I can't get it to work all together.
My code right now is a mess, that's the reason I don't really want to post it here. I looked at different tutorials and copy pasted some code together. Would be better to upload my CI folder I guess.

Some of the tutorials I looked at:

- [Dive into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/history.html)
- [HTML5 demos](http://html5demos.com/history)
- [Mozilla manipulating the browser history](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)
- [Saner HTML5 history](https://bcherry.net/playground/sanerhtml5history)
- [Github: History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js)

(max. number of links reached :/)

I think my main problem is, that everybody tries to make it compatible with all browsers and different versions, adds scripts/jQuery plugins and whatnot and I get confused by all the additional code. There is more code between my script-tags then actual html content.
Could somebody post the most basic method how to use HTML5 for my example page?

---

**My failed attemp:**
On my test page, when I go back, the URL changes, but the div box will still show the same content, not the old one. I also don't know how to change the URL in the script according to the href attribute from the link. Is there something like $(this).attr('href'), that changes according to which link I click? Right now I would have to use a script for every link, which of course is bad.
When I refresh the site, CodeIgniter kicks in and loads the view, but really only the view by itself, the one I loaded with ajax, not the whole page. But I guess that should be easy to fix with a layout and the right controller settings. Haven't paid much attention to this yet.

---

Thanks in advance for any help.
If you have suggestions, ideas, or simple just want to mention something, please let me know.

regards
DiLer

Answer (score 9):

I've put up a successful minimal example of HTML5 history here: http://cairo140.github.com/html5-history-example/one.html

The easiest way to get into HTML5 pushstate in my opinion is to ignore the framework for a while and use the most simplistic state transition possible: a wholesale replacement of the `<body>` and `<title>` elements. Outside of those elements, the rest of the markup is probably just boilerplate, although if it varies (e.g., if you change the class on HTML in the backend), you can adapt that.

What a dynamic backend like CI does is essentially fake the existence of data at particular locations (identified by the URL) by generating it dynamically on the fly. We can abstract away from the effect of the framework by literally creating the resources and putting them in locations through which your web server (Apache, probably) will simply identify them and feed them on through. We'll have a very simple file system structure relative to the domain root:

```
/one.html
/two.html
/assets/application.js
```

Those are the only three files we're working with.

Here's the code for the two HTML files. If you're at the level when you're dealing with HTML5 features, you should be able to understand the markup, but if I didn't make something clear, just leave a comment, and I'll walk you through it:

### one.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/application.js"></script>
    <title>One</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>One</h1>
      <a href="two.html">Two</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### two.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/application.js"></script>
    <title>Two</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Two</h1>
      <a href="one.html">One</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You'll notice that if you load `one.html` through your browser, you can click on the link to `two.html`, which will load and display a new page. And from `two.html`, you can do the same back to `one.html`. Cool.

Now, for the history part:

### assets/application.js

```
$(function(){
    var replacePage = function(url) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data){
                var dom = $(data);
                var title = dom.filter('title').text();
                var html = dom.filter('.container').html();
                $('title').text(title);
                $('.container').html(html);
            }
        });
    }

    $('a').live('click', function(e){
        history.pushState(null, null, this.href);
        replacePage(this.href);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(window).bind('popstate', function(){
        replacePage(location.pathname);
    });
});
```

### How it works

I define `replacePage` within the jQuery ready callback to do some straightforward loading of the URL in the argument and to replace the contents of the `title` and `.container` elements with those retrieved remotely.

The `live` call means that any link clicked on the page will trigger the callback, and the callback pushes the state to the `href` in the link and calls `replacePage`. It also uses `e.preventDefault` to prevent the link from being processed the normal way.

Finally, there's a `popstate` event that fires when a user uses browser-based page navigation (back, forward). We bind a simple callback to that event. Of note is that I couldn't get the version on the Dive Into HTML page to work for some reason in FF for Mac. No clue why.

### How to extend it

This extremely basic example can more or less be transplanted onto any site because it does a very uncreative transition: HTML replacement. I suggest you can use this as a foundation and transition into more creative transitions. One example of what you could do would be to emulate what Github does with the directory navigation in its repositories. It's an intermediate manoever that requires floats and overflow management. You could start with a simpler transition like appending the `.container` in the loaded page to the DOM and then animating the old container to `{height: 0}`.

### Addressing your specific "For example"

You're on the right track for using HTML5 history, but you need to clarify your idea of exactly what `/foo` and `/bar` will contain. Basically, you're going to have three pages: `/`, `/foo`, and `/bar`. `/` will have an empty container div. `/foo` will be identical to `/` except in that container div has some foo content in it. `/bar` will be identical to `/foo` except in that the container div has some bar content in it. Now, the question comes to how you would extract the contents of the container through Javascript. Assuming that your `/foo` `body` tag looked something like this:

```
<body>
  <a href="/foo">foo</a>
  <a href="/bar">bar</a>
  <div class="container">foo</div>
</body>
```

Then you would extract it from the response `data` through `var html = $(data).filter('.container').html()` and then put it back into the parent page through `$('.container').html(html)`. You use `filter` instead of the much more reasonable `find` because from some wacky reason, jQuery's DOM parser produces a jQuery object containing every child of the `head` and every child of the `body` elements instead of just a jQuery object wrapping the `html` element. I don't know why.

The rest is just adapting this back into the "vanilla" version above. If you are stuck at any particular stage, let me know, and I can guide you better though it.

### Code

https://github.com/cairo140/html5-history-example

Comment: Thanks a lot! But do I understand it correctly, that this example requires to build every page by hand with all the html, head, etc. so it can be seen as a single page? I added a navigation with 5 links on top of the "container" div, so it's available throughout the website and made 4 new html pages like the one.html with different text and without the navigation. It works wounderful unless I hit F5 of course, then the navigation is gone. What would a good solution to this look like? PHP include? Codeigniter views? Have to make some tests with CI, I like it and use it for more than just URLs.

Comment: To your first question, I build each page by hand here just because the HTML is the ultimate output of the PHP framework. HTML5 history is a frontend technology, so I abstracted away from the backend application code. You're free to generate the equivalents of `one.html` and `two.html`.

Comment: To your second question on how hitting F5 kills the navigation. You just need to make sure the navigation is also there on the second URL. The "different" content that you'd asynchronously load would be in some identifiable `div`, but all such pages would have the same boilerplate header and navigation, presumably prepared through `include` or some view template.

Comment: I tried a few things with CodeIgniter, but I guess it's not possible. Maybe it's just easier to place all sites within one folder and don't use CI for URLs and use php include. Would it be possible to create more subfolders to organize the sites better? Would I have to change the .js file for that? And another thing: do I have to change the javasrcipt to load .php files instead of html files? I had some issues and thought it might be the extension.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this example since it's a complete one. It very helped me understand how to manage the HistoryAPI for a ajax driven website using jQuery. Since `$.live` is deprecated, do you know if it's still working with `$.on` ? If not, maybe you should update your answer.

Comment: @Tareck117 I haven't worked with jQuery in a while, so I wouldn't feel confident to write idiomatic jQuery to share to the world. If you or anyone want to test it out with a more contemporary interface, I'll happily accept edits.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your controller:

```
if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request())
    $this->load->view('header');

$this->load->view('your_view', $data);

if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request())
    $this->load->view('footer');
```